# Standard problem sets for metaheuristics

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, simulation

I'm wanting to dabble with metaheuristics and am interested to know what the "hello world" problem sets are.

In other words, what are the common problems (e.g Traveling Salesman, Vehicle Routing Problem, Maze Solving) to test various algorithms against in order to compare algorithm design?

Comment: What you have tried searching for so far?

Comment: Apart from TS, VRP and MS, the only thing that turns up when searching  are actual algorithms to apply and not problems themselves

Comment: I think this is problem specific. You can look at e.g. DIMACS (TSP) instances for a "standard" set.

Comment: @Juho awesome, I haven't seen DIMACS' TSP contest before. Thanks

Comment: Just stumbled upon http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/

Answer (score 1):

are these any good to you?

Binary Welded Tree (BWT). To ﬁnd a labeled node in a 
graph

BooleanFormula(BF). To evaluate a NAND formula

ClassNumber (CL). To approximate the class group of a real 
quadratic numberﬁeld

GroundStateEstimation(GSE). To compute the ground state 
energy level of a particular molecule

QuantumLinear Systems(QLS). To solve a linear system of 
equations

UniqueShortest Vector (USV). To choose the shortest vector 
among a given set

Triangle Finding(TF). To exhibit a triangle inside a dense 
graph

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Although it looks like I'll be playing with the TSP for a long while...

Comment: ??? how is BF a "heuristic"? etc?

Comment: i just happened to have saved a list of problems i was going to look into. thats all the relevance i had. i have found another resource recently with some machine learning algorithms which look interesting too :D